# Ruby how to reset class methods

Tags: ruby

Using module_eval, my code allows me to dynamically create and add new methods to a class based on input parameters. See this post for an example
[Ruby class_eval and yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039826/ruby-classeval-and-yield)

Now my question is how do I reset the class back to its original methods? Is there a simple method I can use to reset a class back to it's original state? The reason for this is that once new methods are added to the class, they persists and I need to be get rid of them if I create a new object with a different set of methods.

Also I must apologize if this question doesn't quite make sense, I've been up for 24 hours and probably needed to get some rest to think clearly. If this is not clear, I can provide an example. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Added complete solution

If you keep a list of the methods added in your earlier post, you can use `remove_method` to remove these methods with something like:

```
class MyTest
  @@methods_list = []

  def self.show_methods
    @@methods_list
  end

  def self.reset_methods
    @@methods_list.each do |method|
      remove_method(method)
    end
    @@methods_list = []
  end

  def self.add_methods
    define_method("method1")  { puts "This is method1" }
    define_method("method2")  { puts "This is method2" }
    true
  end

  def self.method_added(method_name)
    @@methods_list << method_name.to_s
    puts "Added: " + method_name.to_s + ", list: " + @@methods_list.inspect
  end
end
```

Now you can try out the following:

```
>> require 'mytest.rb'
>> t = MyTest.new # => #<MyTest:0x2b1e293247f0>
>> MyTest.add_methods
Added: method1, list: ["method1"]
Added: method2, list: ["method1", "method2"]
>> t.method1 # Method is available:
This is method1
>> MyTest.reset_methods
>> t.method1 # Method is undefined now, so we'd expect an error
NoMethodError: undefined method `method1' for #<MyTest:0x2b1e293247f0>
    from (irb):6
```

Comment: For this solution, there is a method_added(method_name) that you can define that will be called everytime a method is added

Comment: I tried this but got this error "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)", weird.

Comment: Turns out that my error has to do with dynamically generated methods using module_eval not showing up in MyClass, huh.

Comment: What if you use define_method (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001654) to create your dynamic methods? Is remove_method working now?

Comment: I added a complete example, complete with the output I got using Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Thanks Veger, your example code works perfectly, my error before was due to calling self.reset_methods or remove_method from inside the class itself, any idea why that barfed?

Answer (score 1):

I would take one of two tacks:

- either move the original class methods to a module, which you can re-`include` later
- or use `module_eval` on a subclass of the original class, and just get a new subclass when you want to reset.

The second's a little easier to do:

```
 subklass = Class.new(MyAwesomeClass)
 subklass.module_eval #...

 # ok, I'm done, I want to reset
 subklass = Class.new(MyAwesomeClass)
```

Comment: I agree.  If you will need to reset the class, then your best bet is to use a subclass.  Keep your base class unmodified and create a subclass if you want to dynamically add methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a facility, and I would probably think that your code could be better structured if you need one, but there are a few things you can try:

- Override the new methods with variants that will throw an exception, or do nothing.  If you know the names of the new methods, it'd be pretty easy to do.

  Instead of adding methods to one class, create an anonymous subclass that inherits from the base class, to which you add your methods.  (See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945238/dynamically-create-a-class-without-a-namespace) for a means of doing this.)  Then, your base class is still unmodified, so there'd be no need to reset it.

HTH